# How to assign a value to [any]

Tags: swift, any

When I set `c` to `a`

```
var a: [Any]
var c: Array<PostCategory>
```

error shown:

> cannot convert value of type 'Array' to expected argument type
>   [Any]

how to solve the problem?

Comment: Where's the actual assignment taking place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't \[SomeStruct\] convertible to \[Any\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-arent-somestruct-convertible-to-any)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit misleading but try initializing the array before assigning it:

```
var c: Array<PostCategory> = []
```

...or...

```
var c = Array<PostCategory>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet your `PostCategory` is a `struct`. Apparently struct arrays aren't convertible to an Any array. This is weird because all types conforms to the Any protocol.

If you change the `PostCategory` to a `class` instead, it should work fine. You might need to create a new initializer for the class though, since classes doesn't give you the same default initializer as a struct does.

Comment: Yes, PostCategory is a struct, Is there anything equivalent of Any for struct